# How do I make a cover image for website with fixed height but width that stretches?

Tags: html, css

How can I display a cover image at the top of a web page that stretches when the width of the screen is bigger than the width of the image, but that retains a fixed height?

Here is a page with the behavior I am trying to emulate.
http://outsite.co/san-diego/

Here is the link to the page I am trying to apply it to.
http://phrasemates.com/xcode-developer-language-app.html

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That would be an element with specified `height`, and a large `background-image` with `background-position` set to `50%` or `center`, and `background-size` set to `cover` or `auto 100%` (for some older browsers).

```
div.wide{
    height:500px;
    background-image: url(path/to/big.jpg);
    background-position: 50%;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

to add to what Isaac Lubow said, i would also add an overflow rules in there so it would look like

```
    div.wide {
    height:500px;
    background-image: url(path/to/big.jpg);
    background-position: 50%;
    background-size: cover;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Adding `overflow: hidden;` will make sure that the image doesnt bleed anywhere. however it may not be necessary, just depends on your setup.

Answer (score 0):

You could also set the width to 100vw and retain the set height of 500px. This would fill the width of the viewing window but retain your height.